# Renamimg time dimension while using CRU dataset in Python

Tags: pandas, netcdf4

I have downloaded a CRU dataset as follows;

```
data = netCDF4.Dataset('cru_ts4.04.2011.2019.tmn.dat.nc')
print(data.variables.keys())
dict_keys(['lon', 'lat', 'time', 'tmn', 'stn'])
```

The `time` variable has 108 entries given by 12 months times 9 years. Is it possible to relabel them as month_year format, for e.g. Jan_2011, Feb_2012 etc. Kindly advise

Comment: `data.variables['time']=pd.to_datetime(data.variables['time']).dt.strftime('%b_%Y')`?

Comment: appreciate your response. can you kindly provide full example with your soln. so that I can accept it.thanks

Comment: Thanks Sir btw Did the above comment works? because Sir I don't know anything about netCDF

Comment: actually this is the error I am getting after above suggestion;
TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series